# Undefined Control Sequence (with installed package)?

Tags: tables

I am trying to make a table that includes sums. This is what my code looks like:

```
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{ || c  c  c  c || }
    \hline
    Line & Cost & Executions \\ [0.5ex]
    \hline\hline
    1 & $c_1$ & n -1 \\
    \hline
    2 & $c_2$ & $sum{ j=1}^{\n} j$ \\
    \hline
    3 & $c_3$ & $sum{ j=1}^{\n} j - 1$ \\
    \hline
    4 & $c_4$ & $sum{ j=1}^{\n} j - 1$ \\ [lex]
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
```

I get the error that the first line including a sum has an undefined control sequence. I have the package: \usepackage{amsmath}.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: It is `\sum`, not `sum`, and `_{j=1}`, not `{j=1}`, and `^n` or `^{n}`, not `^{\n}`, and `[1ex]`, not `[lex]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Completed code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{2pt}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{2pt}
\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{ || Sc  Sc  Sc  Sc || }
    \hline
    Line & Cost & Executions \\ 
    \hline\hline
    1 & $c_1$ & $n -1$ \\
    \hline
    2 & $c_2$ & $\sum_{j=1}^{n} j$ \\
    \hline
    3 & $c_3$ & $\sum_{j=1}^{n} j - 1$ \\
    \hline
    4 & $c_4$ & $\sum_{j=1}^{n} j - 1$ \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Changes taken:

1. `sum` to `\sum`
2. `{ j=1}` to `_{j=1}` (to make `j=1` subscript)
3. `\n` to `n`. `\n` is undefined, hence the compilation error
4. `n -1` to math mode
5. Use `cellspace` to adjust height of cells instead of manually adding `[1ex]`, etc., which is worse. Btw it is `[1ex]` instead of `[lex]`

---

Recommended table:

1. Remove all vertical lines
2. Use `booktabs`, which provides `\toprule`, `\midrule` and `\bottomrule` for beautiful tables
3. Make phantom height so that all rows have the same height

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{2pt}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{2pt}
\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{Sc  Sc  Sc  Sc}
    \toprule
    Line & Cost & Executions \\ 
    \midrule
    1 & $c_1$ & $n -1\vphantom{\sum_{j=1}^n}$ \\
    2 & $c_2$ & $\sum_{j=1}^{n} j$ \\
    3 & $c_3$ & $\sum_{j=1}^{n} j - 1$ \\
    4 & $c_4$ & $\sum_{j=1}^{n} j - 1$ \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe the code would be simpler with an `array` or a `matrix` environment?